# orientdb-community-2.1.12 history tab

Tags: orientdb-2.1

Is there any way that I can help get the "Search in history" dialog box in the orientdb-community-2.1.12 web interface to work?  When I type a word into it, for instance "select" it returns "Warning You are clearing history. Are you sure?"  just as if you clicked on the trash can.

I would be very happy to register this as a bug if it really is.

Sincerely,

Flint

Answer (score 0):

One work around is to run the command line version of orientdb.  You do this by starting the console.sh program.  This keeps a shell history, and while it is not so convenient to cut and paste between windows, heck. it works.

To get a history file, reasonable way is to grep through:
orientdb/orientdb-community-2.1.12/bin/.orientdb_history

Regards,

Flint